# Passing parameter to a function parameter is not working

Tags: go

I have written the following code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type student struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
    City string
}

func takeFuncAsParam(a func(st student, c string) bool, s []student) []student {
    var result []student
    for _, e := range s {
        if a(e,c) {
            result = append(result, e)
        }
    }
    return result
}

func main() {
    s1 := student{"Subir", 30, "Bolpur"}
    s2 := student{"Mainak", 29, "Bolpur"}
    s := []student{s1, s2}
    filterByName := func(s student, c string) bool {
        return strings.Contains(s.Name, c)

    }
    result := takeFuncAsParam(filterByName, s)

    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

i am getting compilation error in line number 17.

```
    undefined: c
```

So how can I pass a parameter to filterByName function in this case (c string)?

Comment: Where is `c` defined in the scope of `main` function?

Comment: `takeFuncAsParam(filterByName, s)` -- filter by what name? What/Where is the name by which you want to filter? Did you perhaps wanted to do something like [this](https://go.dev/play/p/e3QemrZxB-S)?

Comment: @mkopriva yes I am trying to do that. Let me read how you did it.

Comment: I am not getting it. @mkopriva please add your answer and explain a bit. Are you taking 2 functions as input and returning a boolean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the argument type of `takeFuncAsParam` to be `func(student) bool`, i.e. drop the `c string` parameter, like so:

```golang
func takeFuncAsParam(fn func(student) bool, s []student) []student {
    var result []student
    for _, e := range s {
        if fn(e) {
            result = append(result, e)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Change the `filterByName` to be a function that takes the `name` argument by which to filter and returns a new function of the type required by `takeFuncAsParam`, i.e. `func(student) bool`, like so:

```golang
filterByName := func(name string) func(student) bool {
    return func(s student) bool {
        return strings.Contains(s.Name, name)
    }
}
```

To use the new filter function you need to call it with the `name` argument by which to filter and then pass the returned function to `takeFuncAsParam`, like so:

```golang
fn := filterByName("Subir")
result := takeFuncAsParam(fn, s)

// or

result := takeFuncAsParam(filterByName("Subir"), s)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/e3QemrZxB-S